# How do I change the 'Type' designation of PDFs without changing the default PDF reader?

Tags: windows-10, pdf, foxit-reader

I use the foxit pdf reader and am happy enough with it. However, when I filter files in a directory in windows using the 'type' column, Foxit has set all PDFs to be 'Foxit PDF Reader Document'. Is there a registry entry whereby I can change this back to 'PDF file'?

Screen grab of the offending type designation:

[image: Screen grab of the offending type designation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Start the Registry Editor (`regedit.exe`)
2. Go to the following key:

   `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\FoxitReader.Document`
3. Backup the branch by exporting it to a .reg file.
4. In the right-pane, right-click `(default)` and choose Delete.
   [image]
5. Logoff and log back in for the change to take effect.

The Type column in the folder will now read "PDF File". Optionally, you can assign a custom type/description in that registry location.

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.